# Duplicate input when adding

Tags: javascript, html, css

The idea of the script is that it adds sections and text boxes to them. If I add one section and adds input to it, everything plays. However, when I add the other one - in one of them the prompt is duplicated and I can not get why, I put code to check what I mean.

```js
$("#add_section").on("click", function() {
   
   var sectionid = $(".sekcja").length;
   $("#sectionid").val(sectionid);
   var sectionwidth = prompt("Section width");
   $("#sectionwidth").val(sectionwidth);
   var sectionheight = prompt("Section height");
   $("#sectionheight").val(sectionheight);
   var bg = prompt("Section background color");
   $("#bg").val(bg);
   var sectioncolor = prompt("Section font color");
   $("#sectioncolor").val(sectioncolor);
   $("#new_section").append('<div class="section" style="width: '+ sectionwidth +'px; min-height: '+ sectionheight +'px; background: #'+ bg +'; color: #'+ sectioncolor +';"><button type="button" class="add_text">Add text</button></div>');
   $(".add_text").on("click", function() {
    
    var inputid = $('.sample').length;
    $("#inputid").val(inputid);
    var inputwidth = prompt("Width text area");
    $("#inputwidth").val(inputwidth);
    $(this).parent().append('<input type="text" class="sample" style="width: '+ inputwidth +'px;" placeholder="Sample text..." name="sample['+inputid+']"/>');
    
   });

   if ($(".section").length > 0) {
    $("#default-section").css("display","none"); 
   }

   if(sectionwidth < 1050) {
    $(".section").css("float","left"); 
   }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="new_section">
<div id="default-section">Default</div>
</div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<button type="button" id="add_section">Add section</button>
```

Comment: It looks like to attach a `click` event handler to `.add_text` button(s) every time someone clicks on the "Add Section" button. You should move out the `$(".add_text").on("click", function() { ... }` part from the section click handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is you can add a `id` like `@Pete` answer

If you don't want to add `id` then move `$(".add_text").on("click")` outside and bind it with `#new_section`. See below code:

Move `$(".add_text").on("click", function() );` outside and

```js
$("#add_section").on("click", function() {
   
   var sectionid = $(".sekcja").length;
   $("#sectionid").val(sectionid);
   var sectionwidth = prompt("Section width");
   $("#sectionwidth").val(sectionwidth);
   var sectionheight = prompt("Section height");
   $("#sectionheight").val(sectionheight);
   var bg = prompt("Section background color");
   $("#bg").val(bg);
   var sectioncolor = prompt("Section font color");
   $("#sectioncolor").val(sectioncolor);
   $("#new_section").append('<div class="section" style="width: '+ sectionwidth +'px; min-height: '+ sectionheight +'px; background: #'+ bg +'; color: #'+ sectioncolor +';"><button type="button" class="add_text">Add text</button></div>');
   

   if ($(".section").length > 0) {
    $("#default-section").css("display","none"); 
   }

   if(sectionwidth < 1050) {
    $(".section").css("float","left"); 
   }

});

$("#new_section").on("click", ".add_text", function() {
    
 var inputid = $('.sample').length;
 $("#inputid").val(inputid);
 var inputwidth = prompt("Width text area");
 $("#inputwidth").val(inputwidth);
 $(this).parent().append('<input type="text" class="sample" style="width: '+ inputwidth +'px;" placeholder="Sample text..." name="sample['+inputid+']"/>');
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="new_section">
<div id="default-section">Default</div>
</div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<button type="button" id="add_section">Add section</button>
```

Comment: Your way is the simplest and probably the most effective method. It works, thanks dude :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on this line:

```
$(".add_text").on("click", function() {
```

Each time you click on "#add_section", you're adding ***another*** click event handler to ***every element*** that has the "add_text" class assigned to it.

I'd suggest that you generate a unique id for the button you're creating on the line above and use that to assign the click event handler.

eg:

```
var id = "cmd_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999);
$("#new_section").append('<div class="section" style="width: '+ sectionwidth +'px; min-height: '+ sectionheight +'px; background: #'+ bg +'; color: #'+ sectioncolor +';"><button type="button" id="' + id + '" class="add_text">Add text</button></div>');
$("#"+id).on("click", function() {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem is that your  `$(".add_text").on("click"` event gets fired for every element with class `.add_text` that is present on the page, meaning the more input fields you've already added, the more times that event gets fired. A solution is to bind and unbind the event handler. Check the code below:

```js
$("#add_section").on("click", function() {
   
   var sectionid = $(".sekcja").length;
   $("#sectionid").val(sectionid);
   var sectionwidth = prompt("Section width");
   $("#sectionwidth").val(sectionwidth);
   var sectionheight = prompt("Section height");
   $("#sectionheight").val(sectionheight);
   var bg = prompt("Section background color");
   $("#bg").val(bg);
   var sectioncolor = prompt("Section font color");
   $("#sectioncolor").val(sectioncolor);
   $("#new_section").append('<div class="section" style="width: '+ sectionwidth +'px; min-height: '+ sectionheight +'px; background: #'+ bg +'; color: #'+ sectioncolor +';"><button type="button" class="add_text">Add text</button></div>');
   $('.add_text').unbind('click', addTextHandler);
   $('.add_text').bind('click', addTextHandler);

   if ($(".section").length > 0) {
    $("#default-section").css("display","none"); 
   }

   if(sectionwidth < 1050) {
    $(".section").css("float","left"); 
   }

  });

var addTextHandler = function() {
    var inputid = $('.sample').length;
    $("#inputid").val(inputid);
    var inputwidth = prompt("Width text area");
    $("#inputwidth").val(inputwidth);
    $(this).parent().append('<input type="text" class="sample" style="width: '+ inputwidth +'px;" placeholder="Sample text..." name="sample['+inputid+']"/>');
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="new_section">
<div id="default-section">Default</div>
</div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<button type="button" id="add_section">Add section</button>
```

I have moved your handler logic to a separate function and then I bind and unbind `.add_class` instead. Hope this helps! :)